# How to optimize the imports in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Approach 1:

```
import { Checkbox, FormControlLabel } from '@mui/material';
```

Approach 2:

```
import { Checkbox } from '@mui/material';
import { FormControlLabel } from '@mui/material';
```

which way you recommend? and why?

Comment: Use the one that minimizes your bundle size. See https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/

Comment: both are same, there there is no difference. If you are using any js bundler, it will automatically remove unused code during build stage.

Answer (score 1):

Optimize your imports as follow:

```js
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
```

You can find information about it here https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/